# ASP.NET Core WebApi EF: Add role to user

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When I add a role to my user (code below), it is not added to the `AspNetRoles` table, but should it?

```
var userResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync (admin, AdminPassword);
var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync (admin, Roles.AdminRole);
```

And when I attach the **Authorize** attribute to a method like so: `(Roles = Roles.AdminRole)`, it says that I do not have the permission: 403 Forbidden.

Also, when I am trying to get roles of a user, it returns an empty array:

```
return await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

Here is my API method:

```
// Host/api/roles/createrole
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.AdminRole)]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole([FromBody] CreateRoleViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    var result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(model.RoleName));

    if (!result.Succeeded)
        return BadRequest(result);

    return Ok();
}
```

Here is my initialization:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    InitializeRoles();
    InitializeAdmin();     
}

#region Private Methods

private void InitializeRoles()
{
    if (_roleManager.Roles.Any())
        return;

    var role = new IdentityRole(Roles.AdminRole);
    var roleResult = _roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Result;
}

private void InitializeAdmin()
{
    if (_userManager.Users.Any())
        return;

    var admin = new User
    {
        UserName = AdminUsername,
        Email = AdminUsername,
    };

    var userResult = _userManager.CreateAsync(admin, AdminPassword).Result;
    var roleResult = _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, Roles.AdminRole).Result;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to call some sort of `_userManager.SaveChanges()` method to commit your changes?

Comment: @Wurd No, do not need

Comment: I recreated Database and initialize it again, but my Admin does not pass validation for the Authorize attribute.

Comment: @NikitaGoncharuk try to use `await` on async tasks. Like so: `var roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Result;`

Comment: Yes, you need that role saved to AspNetRoles table - if you weren't awaiting CreateAsync then you missed IdentityResult.